# create new column based on specific values another columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let say I have this kind of column

```
create table exercise (cust_id varchar, policy_id varchar, end_date date, flag varchar);   
insert into exercise (cust_id, policy_id, end_date, flag)
values
('1', 'a1', '2022-10-12', 'inactive'),
('1', 'a2', '2022-10-20', 'inactive'),
('1', 'a2', '2023-05-15', 'active'),
('2', 'a3', '2022-12-12', 'inactive')
('3', 'a3', '2022-09-18', 'inactive')
('3', 'a1', '2023-12-22', 'active')
```

from that column, we know that 3 customers (1, 2, 3) with 3 products(a1, a2, a3)
Is there any way to make new column,
if the customer have flag 'active' and 'inactive' then it called 'good',
but if the customer only have flag 'inactive' then it called 'bad'

so the output will be look like this, how the logic ???

| cust_id | policy_id | end_date | flag | credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | 2022-10-12 | inactive | good |
| 1 | a2 | 2022-10-20 | inactive | good |
| 1 | a2 | 2023-05-15 | active | good |
| 2 | a3 | 2022-12-12 | inactive | bad |
| 3 | a3 | 2022-09-18 | inactive | good |
| 3 | a1 | 2023-12-22 | active | good |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `COUNT()` here as a window function, along with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT cust_id, policy_id, end_date, flag,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN flag = 'active' THEN 1 END)
                     OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) > 0
            THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END AS credit
FROM exercise
ORDER BY cust_id, end_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0d403/5):

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 'inactive' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) = 1 AND MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 'active' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) = 1 THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END
FROM exercise
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use `inner join` as follows :

This one take on consideration if the last order is active or not.

Example if the last order of a customer is inactive he should be considered as bad customer :

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN s.flag = 'active' THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END as credit
FROM exercise t
join (
  SELECT t.cust_id, t.flag
  FROM (
      select cust_id, max(end_date) as max_date
      from exercise
      group by cust_id
  ) r
  INNER JOIN exercise t
  ON t.cust_id = r.cust_id AND t.end_date = r.max_date
) as s on s.cust_id = t.cust_id
```

check it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/j0TtG62a